# How to connect two docker containers together?

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, tcserver

I have a docker container with tcserver on it with the UI of an application on it. I have a second docker container that is also running tcserver, but this one has the applications engine.

I am trying to get these two to talk to each other somehow, because when I access the UI on the web browser it says that it is not connected to the engine. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the **new allotted ports** of the **App Engine container** to the **UI Container**, because the container can only be accessed by other containers through port.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that:

```
docker run --name engine -d tcserver-engine

docker run --name lala --link engine:tc-engine -d tcserver-ui
```

Inside `lala` container you can get engine container using the selected alias, in this example `tc-engine`

Answer (score 0):

Use **name** and **link** in your **docker run** command or **docker-compose.yml** file?

```
docker run -ti --name server1 -p 8111:8111 ikamman/docker-tc-server
docker run -ti --name server2 --link server1 -p 8112:8111 ikamman/docker-tc-server
docker exec server2 curl server1:8111
```

Will return like this:

```
$ docker exec server2 curl server1:8111
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3546    0  3546    0     0   3290      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  3292
<!--
Page: maintenance-welcome
Stage: FIRST_START_SCREEN
State revision: 12
Timestamp: Wed Jul 27 20:30:06 UTC 2016
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>TeamCity Maintenance &mdash; TeamCity</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="application-name" content="TeamCity"/>
  <meta name="description" content="Powerful Continuous Integration and Build Server"/>
  <link rel="icon" href="/img/icons/TeamCity512.png" sizes="512x512"/>
```